# Application.UnhandledException and original exception message

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro

I'm trying to access original exception which caused UnhandledException but all I see is text contained at UnhandledExceptionEventArgs.Message property;

For example:

- I have view with button with click handler:

> ```
>  private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
>  {
>      throw new NullReferenceException("Test exc");
>  }
> ```

- At App constructor I have subscribed to UnhandledException exception

> ```
>  this.UnhandledException += App_UnhandledException;
>
>  private void App_UnhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
>  {
>      Debug.WriteLine(e.Message);
>      Debug.WriteLine(e.Exception.ToString()); 
>  }
> ```

- As a result I have no option to get original exception text "Test exc". All I have is

> Message = System.NullReferenceException    at
>   W8.Controls.SearchControl.Button_Click_1(Object sender,
>   RoutedEventArgs e)
>
> Exception = System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to
>   an instance of an object.

Thanks in advance for advise!

Answer (score 0):

There are some limitations in what gets propagated to a UnhandledException. [As documented](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.application.unhandledexception.aspx):

> Another limitation is that the UnhandledException event arguments
>   don’t contain as much detail as the original exception. Whenever
>   possible, if the application requires specific processing of a certain
>   exception, it’s always better to catch the exception as it propagates,
>   since more detail will be available. The UnhandledException event
>   arguments expose an exception object through the Exception property.
>   However, the type, message, and stack trace of this exception object
>   are not guaranteed to match those of the original exception that was
>   raised. The event arguments also expose a Message property. In most
>   cases, this will contain the message of the originally raised
>   exception.